# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'EXTRACT (YEAR FROM Starting_Date)'

Tags: ms-access-2010

```
SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM Starting_Date) as Orderyear,
FROM PGME
WHERE ID =1
```

I tried to select the year from the `Starting_Date` which the format is `"15/01/1968"`. But it keep saying the Syntax error. Any recommended? Thank you for advance.

Comment: Remove comma after `Orderyear`

Comment: Thank you quick response, it is still not working

Comment: Is this  a MySQL or a MS-Access query ? The comma is fine if this is a My-SQL query, see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_extract.asp

Comment: basically I copied from w3schools.com/sql/func_extract.asp to the MS-Access query, MS-Access query is not based on MySQL?

Comment: No, Access is not MySQL based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`extract` is a MySQL function that isn't part of the ANSI SQL standard, and from the comments it seems you're trying to use it with MS-Access. Instead, you could consider using the `datepart` function which is more-or-less the MS-Access equivalent. Additionally, as lad2025 noted in his comment, you have a redundant comma after `Orderyear`:

```
SELECT DATEPART("yyyy", Starting_Date) AS orderyear
FROM   pgme
WHERE  id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you Mureinik! It worked!
So for the MS-Access, I have to use SQL Server function instead of MySQL function, is that right?

Comment: @Isaac.H for MS-Access you need to use MS-Access function :-) They are often quite similar, though.